# Displaying nested JSON in a directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to work out how to display nested JSON inside a directive. The code below displays a list of days in a ng-repeat inside a directive. I want to put an ng-click on each row that will update another repeater in the directive that will display a list of that days products.  This new product repeater should be outside the days repeater in another div. I am not sure what that logic should be or where to place it - in the controller or the directive?

So here's the JSON:

```
{
 "currentMonth":"November",
 "calendarDateView":[
{
  "dateOfTheMonth":1,
  "Products":[
  ]
},
{
  "dateOfTheMonth":2,
  "Products":[
    {
      "prodID":311
    },
    {
      "prodID":308
    }
  ]
}
{
  "dateOfTheMonth":3,
  "Products":[
    {
      "prodID":322
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

Which I display in a ng-repeat in a directive...

```
//directive markup (inside calendarController)
<div ng-repeat="date in dates" ng-click>
{{date.dateOfTheMonth}}
</div>

//directive js
 calendarApp.directive('calendarDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: 'calendar/calendarView.html',
        scope: {
            dates: '=dates'
        }
    };
});
```

And I pass the data for the directive via the controller...

```
calendarApp.controller("calendarController", function($scope, availableDates) {
availableDates().success(function(data) {
    $scope.dates = data;
});
});
```

The expected result would be:

```
Days:
1
2 
3
```

Products for day 2: (populates when day is clicked, in this example it's day 2)

```
311
308
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish; can you show an example of your expected result?

Comment: Thanks. I added expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the solution includes custom directive, which you can reuse anywhere you'd like (`setId()` and `getId()` were moved to the directive's isolate scope).

Reworked HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-dir dates="dates"></my-dir>
    <h2>Hi!</h2>
    <my-dir dates="dates"></my-dir>
</div>
```

Template v.1 (`calendar/calendarView.html`) - list of product ID's appears under each `date` object:

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="date in dates.calendarDateView" ng-click="setId($index)">
  {{date.dateOfTheMonth}}
  <div ng-show="getId($index)">
    <div ng-repeat="item in date.Products">Product ID: {{item.prodID}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Template v.2 (`calendar/calendarView.html`) - list of product ID's appears after all `date` objects:

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="date in dates.calendarDateView" ng-click="setId($index)">
    {{date.dateOfTheMonth}}
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="date in dates.calendarDateView">
    <div ng-show="getId($index)">
      <div ng-repeat="item in date.Products">Product ID: {{item.prodID}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller (with `myDir` directive this time):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = {
    "currentMonth":"November",
    "calendarDateView":[
      {
        "dateOfTheMonth":1,
        "Products":[
        ]
      },
      {
        "dateOfTheMonth":2,
        "Products":[
          {
            "prodID":311
          },
          {
            "prodID":308
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "dateOfTheMonth":3,
        "Products":[
          {
            "prodID":322
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}])
 .directive("myDir", function(){
    return {
      restrict: "EA",
      templateUrl: "calendar/calendarView.html", 
      scope: {
        dates: "="
      },
      replace: true, 
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.setId = function(index){
          var id = "id"+index;
          return scope[id] = !scope[id];
        };
        scope.getId = function(index){
          var id = "id" + index;
          return scope[id];
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it can but I was using a directive so it could be reusable in other places in my app. Is this not the right approach?

Comment: Sure, Angular is quite flexible and so it's possible to acomplish things in many different ways. I revised the initial answer, now it includes the directive you wanted.

Comment: Many thanks! One last thing! In the directive the product list displays inside the date ng-repeat. I was hoping to display the products outside of that ng-repeat. So there will first be the list of dates, then as a user clicks a date and it shows that dates available products under the list of dates. Sorry I should have been clearer in my OP

Comment: Updated my post above. If the answer was useful, mark it as such, it is the best `thankyou` for those who help.

Comment: Cool thanks. That fixed it. I moved the ng-show="getId($index)" into the <div ng-repeat="date in dates.calendarDateView" ng-show="getId($index)"> to reduce the mark up as there was a lot of empty divs being created for the products. I'm still not happy with my approach though. As there will be extra product details like images, price etc, would I be better off to create another directive for the product list and pass the 'Products' array of the selected day to it?

Comment: Moving `ng-show` one level up was a good idea :) As for the rest, like i've said earlier Angular is flexible enough and is quite able to acomplish things in various ways, so if you feel that another custom directive with its own template will look nicer, then use it.